# Calc/Place horizontal labels around SVG Donut Graph (NO LIBRARIES)

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am looking to add 'floating' labels around an SVG Donut Graph, as seen below, using only SVG elements and vanilla JS.

The corresponding lines are a plus, but not necessary.

[image]

Building of the dynamic donut/sectors is complete and I have it ported/working correctly within an Angular application. I am using vanilla JS w/Jquery here for ease.

I have scoured StackOverflow and Google to their depths but cannot locate a Question & Answer which provides a compatible solution using an algorithm/code to calculate desired placement. 90% of similar questions reference d3.js while the others reference a different charting library.

Not sure where to begin as I don't think the information I have on the segments is enough to calc placement within the `viewBox`.

I do know the **circumference** of the drawn circles are each `100` with a **radius** of `15.91549430918954`. `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` are calculated and set to each segment to build out the colored segments appropriately.

Is it possible to use what data I have to figure this out? Do I need a little more? How would I translate the calculation to x/y coordinates for the `viewBox`?

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let data = [500,100,350,600];
  let dataTotal = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataTotal += data[i];
  }
  let colors = ['#ce4b99', '#4286f4', '#62f441', '#952ec1'];
  let labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let dataPercent = data[i] / dataTotal;
    let dataVal = 100 * dataPercent;
    var chart = document.getElementById("chart");
    const group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    const node = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    const label = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
    chart.appendChild(group);
    group.appendChild(node);
    group.appendChild(label);
    label.textContent = labels[i];
    label.setAttribute('class', 'data-label');
    label.setAttribute('x', '20%');
    label.setAttribute('y', '20%');
  
    node.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',`${dataVal} ${100 - dataVal}`);
    node.setAttribute('class','donut-segment');
    node.setAttribute('fill','transparent');
    node.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', getOffset(total, i))
    total += dataVal;
    node.setAttribute('stroke', colors[i]);
    node.setAttribute('stroke-width','3');
    node.setAttribute('r','15.91549430918954');
    node.setAttribute('cx','42');
    node.setAttribute('cy','42');
  }
});

function getOffset(total, i) {
  if (i === 0) return 25;
  return ((100 - total) + 25);
}
```

```css
.chart-contain {
  width: 50%;
  margin 0 auto;
}
.data-label {
  font-size: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<div class='chart-contain'>
<svg id='chart' width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 84 84" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="42" cy="42" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="42" cy="42" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3">
  </circle>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not like my answer because I couldn't use your code. I needed to organise the data differently. However I keep the general idea: I'm using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`. I would have used paths instead of strokes.

I'm using a radius of 20, but you may change it back. You can also change it to anything else.

In order to draw the text I calculated the starting angle and the ending angle of your arcs. Then I calculated the middle angle. Once I know the middle angle I can draw the text and the lines.

I'm putting the arcs in the `#chart` group, the text in the `#text` group and the lines in the #lines group.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const XLINK =  'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
let r = 20,cx=42,cy=42;// the attributes for the circle 
let text_r = r + 10; // the radius for the text
let perimeter = 2*r*Math.PI;//the perimeter of the circle
donut.setAttributeNS(null, "r", r);
donut.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", cx);
donut.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", cy);

let data = [
  {
    value:500,
    stroke:'#ce4b99',
    label: 'A' 
  },
    {
    value:100,
    stroke:'#4286f4',
    label: 'B' 
  },
  {
    value:350,
    stroke:'#62f441',
    label: 'C' 
  },
  {
    value:600,
    stroke:'#952ec1',
    label: 'D' 
  } 
]

let total = 0;

data.map(d =>{
  d.temp = total;
  total += d.value;
  
})

data.map(d =>{
  d.offset = map(d.temp,0,total,0, perimeter)
  d.real_value = map(d.value, 0, total, 0, perimeter);  
  d.dashArray = `${d.real_value},${perimeter}`;
  
  /// angles
  let angleStart = -d.offset/r;
  let angleEnd =  (d.offset + d.real_value)/r;
  d.angleMiddle = (angleEnd - angleStart)/2;
    
  // text
  let t = {}
  t.props ={
  x : cx + text_r*Math.cos(d.angleMiddle),
  y : cy + text_r*Math.sin(d.angleMiddle),
  }
  t.textContent = d.label;
  d.text_point = t;
  
  
  //line
  let l = {
  x1 : cx + r*Math.cos(d.angleMiddle),
  y1 : cy + r*Math.sin(d.angleMiddle),
  x2 : cx + .9*text_r*Math.cos(d.angleMiddle),
  y2 : cy + .9*text_r*Math.sin(d.angleMiddle),  
  }
  d.line = l;
})

data.map(d=>{// create a new use element
  d.use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
  d.use.setAttributeNS(XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#donut');
  d.use.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', d.stroke);
  d.use.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-dasharray', d.dashArray);
  d.use.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-dashoffset', -d.offset);
  chart.appendChild(d.use);
  
  drawLine(d.line, lines);
  drawText(d.text_point, text);
    
})

// helpers
function drawLine(o, parent) {
  var line = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'line');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      line.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(line);
  return line;
}

function drawText(o, parent) {
  var text = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
  for (var name in o.props) {
    if (o.props.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      text.setAttributeNS(null, name, o.props[name]);
    }
   text.textContent = o.textContent; 
  }
  parent.appendChild(text);
  return text;
}

function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}

#donut{fill:none; stroke-width:5px;}

text{dominant-baseline:central;text-anchor:middle;font-size: 4px;}
line{stroke:black;stroke-width:.1px}
```

```html
<div class='chart-contain'>
<svg viewBox="0 0 84 84" width="250" class="donut">
  <defs>
     <circle id="donut" cx="42" cy="42" r="20" ></circle>  
  </defs>
  <g id='text'></g>
  <g id='lines'></g>
  <g id='chart'></g>
 
</svg>
</div>
```

In order to get it exactly like yours you may want to rotate the whole chart -Math.PI/2 and then rotate the text back.

Comment: This is great, I can work around / build my models to support this. Exactly what I needed to help with understanding. Kudos.

Comment: hi, what is the purpose of the map function that you have implemented? and could you explain how the arc angle was calculated?

Comment: You can use forEach instead of map if you prefer. The other map - the function is finding a value in a different interval. For example map(7,0, 10, 0, 100): If I have a number 7 in an interval from 0 to 10 what would be it's value in an interval from 0 to 100. The result is 70. I'm using this function to calculate the real value where I need to map the value from the data array between 0 and the perimeter of the circle