# How do I add polylines to my simple svg donut chart? [NO LIBRARIES]

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, graph

I want to build a simple svg donut chart, with labels and polylines connecting the sectors to the label text like this.

[image]

I know this is possible using d3.js like implemented here, but I am restricted to using a simple chart without any libraries.

This is the code I have now;

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 42 42" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" data-per="20" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#49A0CC" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="50 50" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" data-per="30" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#254C66" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="50 50" stroke-dashoffset="75"></circle>   
   <!--   stroke-dashoffset formula:
     100 − All preceding segments’ total length + First segment’s offset = Current segment offset
   -->
  </svg>
</div>
```

Any tips on how to draw polylines and position them properly without overlap?

EDIT: I want to input dynamic data to the component so that it will draw the chart whenever the data is changed.

implementations in d3: [impl1](https://gist.github.com/dbuezas/9306799)

Comment: Add polyline tags with some appropriate values.

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry  I forgot to mention the graph has to redraw based on input data, so it has to be dynamic, the doubt I have is how to get the centroids for the sectors and then draw polylines from there.

Comment: Then you need to write some javascript code to generate it from that input data. At the moment the question is too broad because it's write a charting solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main doubt was calculating the points for the arcs that have to be drawn for a donut chart, which I then understood thanks to this amazing answer by [enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52643570/13261153).

All I had to figure out was adding the third point for the polyline, if the text.xCoordinate was closer to either side of the svg, I moved it either left or right by a preset amount. I also had to split the labels into multiple `<tspan>`s as `<text>` elements would not break the long text and long labels would get clipped off by the SVG. It is also possible to append HTML within a `<foreignObject>` and position it correctly, to overcome the text wrapping issue.

Another option is to use `<path>` elements for generating arcs, but I am not sure how to calculate the centroid of each of the arcs.

Recommended reading:

- [Medium article for `<circle>` donut chart](https://heyoka.medium.com/scratch-made-svg-donut-pie-charts-in-html5-2c587e935d72) kinda like enxaneta's answer, with the attributes explained.
- [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hue94/pen/NgMGWO) with another `<circle>` donut chart
- [`<path>` donut chart](https://dev.to/mustapha/how-to-create-an-interactive-svg-donut-chart-using-angular-19eo) as mentioned above, implemented beautifully by Mustapha.